# Invalid syntax with else statement in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

When I try to run my code it says I have invalid syntax with my else statement, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
import random
import time
username = input("Hello.  Please enter your name, then press 'enter'.  
After you type something, you will need to /n"
                 "click the 'enter' key to send it")
print ("Hello " + username)
time.sleep(3)
game_tutorial_input = input("Do you wish to see the tutorial? (y/n)")
if game_tutorial_input == "y":
    print ("Great!  Press enter after each instruction to move /n" 
"onto the next one.")
    else
        print("Are you sure? (y/n")
```

Answer (score 4):

indent matters in python , make sure the `else` is on the same indent column as the `if`. and as stated you need a `:` at the end of `else`.. ie, `else:`

Answer (score 1):

Try 'else:'

I believe it's missing a colon.

Answer (score 0):

1. indent out the else
2. add a colon to end of the `else`

**Explanation:**

1. `else`, `if`, `elif`, `with` etc.. are statements which need colons after the statement

Answer (score 0):

add colon after else and indentation of else is wrong

```
if game_tutorial_input == "y":
    print ("Great!  Press enter after each instruction to move /n" 
"onto the next one.")
else:
    print("Are you sure? (y/n")
```